# time stamp to date and time javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have this timestamp: `2013-03-22T12:25:19` that I need to convert to something like: `10:41 AM on Mon 07 Oct`

If i use `toString()` i get: `Fri Mar 22 2013 12:25:19 GMT+0000 (GMT)`

What is the simplest code to convert it to what i want?

Do i use `getMonth()` etc to format it or is it best to split it?
I have read a few different answers on here but i am not sure which is the best for this situation. In the past i would simply use something like:

```
d = new Date(myDate);

yyyy = d.getFullYear().toString();
mm = d.getMonth().toString();
dd = d.getDate().toString();
hh = d.getHours().toString();
mi = d.getMinutes().toString();
```

in the case i am not sure it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies but i didn't want to use a library as i needed to keep the size down.

I ended up going for this:

```
function dateFormat(stamp){
  var d = new Date(stamp);
  var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
  var days = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Sat','Sun'];
  var month = months[d.getMonth()];
  var dayText = days[d.getDay()];
  var day = d.getDate();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var min = d.getMinutes();
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12;

  return hours + ':' + min + ' ' + ampm + ' on ' + dayText + ' ' + day + ' ' + month;
}
dateFormat('2013-03-22T17:25:19');
```

It is specialist for what i want but this helps keep the size down.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) it's a pretty nice plugin!

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js"></script>
<script>
alert(new Date().toString("hh:mm tt"));
</script>
</html>
```

Works perfectly - Now for month and week day:

```
var now = new Date();
var dayNames = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");

alert("Today is " + dayNames[now.getDay()] + ".");

var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

alert("The current month is " + monthNames[now.getMonth()]);
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: If you are going to use date.js, please consider using Gregory's fork since the original has been abandoned.  [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info).

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to use an already created library like moment.js!

Use the [built in format options](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to give you the correct output, example:

`moment(yourDateStr).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");`